# Javascript.Дана строка, подсчитать сколько раз встречается a. indexOf

Tags: javascript, массивы

Дана строка, подсчитать сколько раз встречается буква a.

Как я смогу решить эту задачку через метод indexOf ?

Comment: можете, но это не эффективно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если уж очень хочется решить эту задачу, используя `indexOf`, то можете решить таким способом (В следующем примере `indexOf()` используется для поиска всех индексов элемента `a` в строке, которые с помощью `push()` добавляются в другой массив и `length` этого массива будет содержать количество вхождений символа в заданную строку)

```js
const myString = 'простая строка'
var indices = [];
var element = 'а';
var idx = myString.indexOf(element);
while (idx != -1) {
  indices.push(idx);
  idx = myString.indexOf(element, idx + 1);
}

console.log(`В строке "${myString}" символ ${element} встречается ${indices.length} раз(а)`);
```

Второй пример(с учетом мнения [teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran)):

```js
    const myString = 'простая строка'
    var countElements = 0;
    var element = 'а';
    var idx = myString.indexOf(element);
    while (idx != -1) {
      countElements++;
      idx = myString.indexOf(element, idx + 1);
    }

    console.log(`В строке "${myString}" символ ${element} встречается ${countElements} раз(а)`);
```

Comment: и зачем это дело складывать в массив? просто `count++` не достаточно?

Comment: #teran, спасибо, вставил вариант с учетом вашего мнения ,если вы не против, конечно